# How do I interpret this DC motor datasheet?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, design, gears

**Problem summary:**

I need to produce about **0.289 Nm** with a [rack and pinion system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rack_and_pinion) and compress **24 mm** of a **110 mm x 21.6 mm, 0.99 N/mm** [steel spring](https://benl.rs-online.com/web/p/compression-springs/0121242/).

I thought about using with a **10mm pitch diameter** gear with **ten 1mm gear modules** at an angular velocity of about **15rpm** (or **1.571 rad/s**).
Ignoring the efficiency losses, and the friction of the gear system a **12 V** DC motor consuming **37.8 mA** would do the job:

$$E \cdot w=0.454 W$$

$$ V=12 V \quad I =\frac{(E \cdot w)}{V}=37.837 \mathrm{~mA}$$

(*I assumed the torque on the gear to be the same as the work done by compressing the spring and set this to be the electrical power consumed.*)

However, in the real world, things are more complicated and I have been oriented [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/549599/how-do-i-find-the-best-dc-motor-for-my-rack-and-pinion-system). To choose a motor expecting a final efficiency of ***25%*** and, thus, expect using about 4 times more current.

**Motor specs:**

After some research I found a [DC motor](https://befr.rs-online.com/web/p/dc-motors/9211460/) with the following specifications:

```
Supply Voltage                  12 V dc
DC Motor Type                   Geared
Output Speed                    14 rpm
Shaft Diameter                  6mm
Maximum Output Torque           59 Ncm
Gear Ratio                      300:1
Dimensions                      39 (Dia.) x 83.2 mm
Current Rating                  180 mA
```

[image]
[image]

**My questions:**

Because the output speed is about the same as my rack and pinion uses, I imagine my operating conditions will be the same as the graph **Gear ratio 1/300**. ***Is that correct?***

Thinking back now, I assumed the torque on the gear to be the same as the work done by compressing the spring and set this to be the electrical power consumed.***That's wrong, isn't it?***

$$Tangential force \cdot \frac{( pitch diameter)}{2} = torque$$

so if I need about 24N of linear force on my rack, the torque will actually be about **13 Ncm** instead of 29 Ncm like I first thought.
In that case, ***is this motor I found still a good choice?***

Any corrections, comments and/or suggestions are welcome!
For a more thorough description of my problem go to [here](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40524/advice-on-spring-launcher-project)

Answer (score 1):

On the motor spec sheet you are correct to used the "Gear ratio 1/300" graph because that is the motor+gearbox that you intend to purchase. Those other graphs are for different models that the company offers for sale.

I did not have time to dive into all your previous questions. So I will just explain what this motor can do and you can decide if it is satisfactory for your application or not.

Per the 1:300 graph in your post we can identify many different operating conditions. (you can also reference the 1:300 portion of the table):

Since you are only concerned with the torque and RPM you just need to look at the T-N line, the other lines are for figuring out the electrical current (amps) required. Also note that [min-1] = RPM = Revolutions per minute

No load, no resistance = 0Ncm @ 17RPM
Rated load = 98Ncm @ 14RPM
Another possible operating mode = 196Ncm @ 10RPM
Startup, Stalled rotor = 490Ncm @ 0RPM

Torque and RPM are inversely proportional. As the load torque goes up the RPM goes down.
[image: gear ratio graph]